# React Native Drawer Navigation is lagging in react-navigation/native 6.1.1

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/open-sans": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo-google-fonts/poppins": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo-google-fonts/urbanist": "^0.2.2",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.10",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.3.1",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "~47.0.8",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.4",
    "module-name": "^0.0.1-security",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^4.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.1",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
```

My dependencies,

My Drawer Navigation is lagging while open or close it.

Can it be some mistake that I have made?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGz80.png)

Can someone help me to find out this issue?